# It it possible to read a page request parameter from portlet?

Tags: java, portlet, liferay

It is posible for a portlet to read a request parameter of its surrounding page?

E.g. the URL of the page the portlet resides in is http://example.com/mypage?foo=bar
Is it possible to read the "foo" parameter from a portlet that is on that page?

Portlet Container is Liferay 5.2.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved with something like this -

```
HttpServletRequest convertReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
HttpServletRequest originalReq = PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(convertReq);
String productId = originalReq.getParameter("foo");
```

Where request is RenderRequest.

Comment: To add something: The way to get the RenderRequest: RenderRequest request = (RenderRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("javax.portlet.request");

Answer (score 1):

`PortletRequest` class has method `getAttribute()`

You can treat it like `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet found a way besides using platform specific class `com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil`.